# In visual studio 2010 cant able to attach w3wp process for debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-7

I am using Visual studio 2010. I have hosted my application in IIS and trying to attach the process in visual studio by clicking

```
Alt + Ctrl + P
```

In "Attach to Process" window can't able to find w3wp process to attach. I am in need to debug the IIS process. Anyone suggest me how to fix this issue or is there any other alternative way to attach the process hosted in IIS.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is something called session isolation. Learn what it is and what it does. You have to run VS as admin and also in the attach dialog choose to show all processes of all sessions.

Comment: If running as an administrator solves your issue, then please delete the question.

Comment: "Show Process in All session" solves my problem Thanks @LexLi

Answer (score 0):

w3wp.exe won't show in the running process' unless there is actually an instance of the web application running.

Try to access your web page first, when it is displayed for the first time, try to attach your debugger. The process should now show up.